# Child object deforms wiedly when terget is posed

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

Have a rigged character and rigged swing I am animating. I added an object constrains to the character's armature or rig as 'Child of' the swing bone. Below are screenshots

Default position
[image]

Posed position sample. The character is sheared and the hand particularly is also wobbled badly
[image]

Please do kindly advise on what I can change to avoid this. Thanks

Comment: I think you have a similar problem as this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73782/deforming-when-no-deform-is-wanted/

Comment: Thanks - hope to check this out. I downloaded the swing rigged already and when I finally gave it a new bone just for a test, the shear issue issue seemed to be absent. Meaning that whatever that has to be altered is on the swing armature's end. For the time being I had decided to fully rig the swing afresh and proceed from there.