# Bones Deforming Mesh that it's attached to

Tags: bones

I'm very new to modeling, and have no backround on it either! I am having some trouble with bones and meshes. Basically, I have the bones to be the parent of the mesh, however when I attempt to move them in Pose mode, they deform and scale in weird ways. I'm just trying to make some robot legs. [image: Before Moving Bones]

[image: After Moving Bones (Not Happy Leg)]

Comment: How is the mesh parented to the armature? Is it parented to the object, or the bone? Is it using an armature modifier? Can you upload a .blend?

Comment: Probably a bone scale problem (at least), see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73782/deforming-when-no-deform-is-wanted/73786#73786

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you've scaled your bone on its Y axis (Z global axis when the bone stands up) when you were in *Pose* mode. You need to select it in *Pose* mode and press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to reset the scale. The parented mesh will come back to its normal proportion by the way...

[image]

If you want your bone to be longer than it is, you need to scale it in *Edit* mode, not *Pose* mode, which is made for animation. If you think that the Octahedral display mode is not convenient, you can switch to B-Bone mode for example, then you can change the bone thickness with 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and drag.

[image]

Comment: I've rested the scale, however I can't seem to actually scale the bone on only one axis. It seems to scale the entirety of it, to make all the axis equal.

Comment: if you use the scale in the N panel, as I show, you scale on the axis you want, but anyway, I don't understand why you don't want to scale it entirely, scale in Pose mode as only a sense if you want to scale during an animation, don't use it to deform or correct your shape in any other case, why did you actually use it?

Comment: The bone keeps poking out of the mesh if not scaled correctly, as the mesh on the bottom is just a pyramid, so it goes inward